# Get Root Domain Name Or Server name + Port in Java?

Tags: java

Ok, I am testing my WebApp in my Local Server that have home page url like this "`http://127.0.0.0:8080`".

Ok, in My Godaddy VPS, I have the same app installed and my home oage url is "`mydomain.com`"

In the ROOT folder, I have a folder "staticpage". There are many files in there:

/staticpage/test.txt
/staticpage/test2.txt
...

How to program in Java to get the location of staticpage folder?

I did like this

```
    StringBuilder rootDomainNameSb = new StringBuilder("http://");
    rootDomainNameSb.append(httpRequest.getServerName());
    if (httpRequest.getServerPort() != 0) {
      rootDomainNameSb.append(":");
      rootDomainNameSb.append(httpRequest.getServerPort());
    }
    String rootDomainName=rootDomainNameSb.toString(); // this will print out http://127.0.0.0:8080
    String finalUrl=rootDomainName+"/staticpage/test.txt";
```

The above code works fine, but I am not sure whether it will work in VPS?

in VPS, it's `mydomain.com` which was mapped to `http://127.0.0.0:8080`

Will the above code work Ok in VPS?

Comment: You'll know when you test it. Why on earth would you ask us?

Comment: When you've tested it, learn about relative urls.

Comment: the manager control the VPS right now. I can only access it when he come back 2 weeks later

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easier and just use a relative path.

Comment: Or an absolute path without base URL like `/index.html` (instead of `index.html` which is relative to the current directory)

Comment: InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/staticpage/"+tokenName+".txt"); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); & staticpage folder inside WEB-INF\classes\myapp\server\staticpage, but it showed a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Found 1 solution:

```
        String absolutePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf("/"));

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(absolutePath+"/project/server/staticpage/test.txt");
```